# Dynamic Button creation doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton, dynamically-generated

Can't figure out what's wrong -
here's the implementation of **viewDidLoad()** in UIViewController;
I have 3 different UI elements dynamically created: UIImageView, UIButton and UILabel;
though they are initiated in almost the same way, it turns out that button is not created correctly!

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.


self.mainImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width)];
[self.view addSubview:self.mainImageView];
self.mainImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"main"];


self.buttonTraining = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[self.view insertSubview:self.buttonTraining aboveSubview:self.mainImageView];
self.buttonTraining.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
self.buttonTraining.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.buttonTraining.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:30];
[self.buttonTraining setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Training", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.buttonTraining sizeToFit];

if (self.view.frame.size.height <= 480) {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height);
} else {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height * 2);
}

[self.buttonTraining addTarget:self action:@selector(startTraining) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


self.titleLabel = [UILabel new];
[self.view insertSubview:self.titleLabel aboveSubview:self.mainImageView];
self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:30];
self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.titleLabel.text = @"text";
[self.titleLabel sizeToFit];

self.titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width - self.titleLabel.frame.size.width) / 2.0f + 18, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.origin.y + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + 8, self.titleLabel.frame.size.width, self.titleLabel.frame.size.height);}
```

The problem is that I couldn't manage to reproduce the issue! I tested the app on the iPhone simulator (iPhone 4s - iPhone 6 Plus) provided by Xcode and on my iPhone 5 (both via connecting to Xcode and via distributing using Ad Hoc provisioning), iOS 8.0-8.4. Everything is ok. But I've received screenshots (App Store Review) with no button and they said it just doesn't appear after launching the app.

UIImageView and UILabel work well.

Have you any ideas why?! I can guarantee that it's the only place in my code where these UI elements are affected. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check that the buttonTraining property is strong, not weak.

Comment: @TomSwift you were right, thanks! The problem was that the button was declared as a weak property. I can't mark (accept) your answer though... it's a comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by @TomSwift who pointed out that dynamically created button should be a strong property, not weak.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue lies in below code..

self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height is null initially sometimes. Where u are setting buttonTraining height or frame initially after creating button dynamically?

```
if (self.view.frame.size.height <= 480) {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height);
} else {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height * 2);
}
```

So, Instead of self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height use some static value or as below

```
if (self.view.frame.size.height <= 480) {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.mainImageView.frame.size.height);//set static value for self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height
} else {
    self.buttonTraining.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.mainImageView.frame.origin.y + self.mainImageView.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.mainImageView.frame.size.height * 2);//set static value for self.buttonTraining.frame.size.height
}
```

Once Check it..
Hope it helps you...!